# Why I get a wrong answer when I evaluate $\int\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}dx$ in different way?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is obvious that:$$I=\int\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}dx=\ln\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|$$

But I am trying to evaluate the integral in different way (relevant to even and odd functions):

$$I=\int\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}dx=\int\underbrace{\frac1{x-1}}_{f_{(x)}}+\frac{-1}{x+1}dx$$

I consider $\frac1{x-1}=f(x)$ then $\frac{-1}{x+1}=f(-x)$ and we have:
$$I=\int f(x)+f(-x) dx=F(x)+F(-x)$$

Where $F(x)$ and $F(-x)$ are antiderivative of $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ respectively.

$F(x)=\int\frac{1}{x-1}dx=\ln|x-1|$ then $F(-x)=\ln|-x-1|=\ln|x+1|$. Therefore:

$$I=\ln|x-1|+\ln|x+1|=\ln|x^2-1|$$

Why I get a wrong answer in this method?

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dx}F(-x)=-f(-x)$

Comment: The antiderivative of $f(-x)$ is $-F(-x)$, not $F(-x)$. That should do it.

Comment: I thought every time we have $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ Then antiderivative of $f(-x)$ is always $F(-x)$. So isn't this a true statement? when this hold?

Comment: It seems to me rare that that the antiderivative of $f(-x)$ ever is $F(-x)$ [except ofcourse $f\equiv 0$, or some similar case]. Because if $(F(-x))'=f(-x)$ then also $f(-x)=(F(-x))'=-F'(-x)=-f(-x)$ so $2f(-x)=0$.